# Meteor: Shuffle array then map indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, meteor

I am trying to shuffle an array of objects from a mongo collection (**items**) before mapping indexes to it.

The way that I have it now doesn't include the shuffling and only maps indexes to each object in the template helper. Like this:

```
dayItems: function() {
    return this.dayItems.map(function(item, index) {
        item.index = index;
        return item;
    });
},
```

I've tried shuffling items without mapping indexes (which works). Like this:
**EDIT: Sorry, this doesn't seem to work even on its own. Any ideas why?**

```
dayItems: function() {
    return _.shuffle(this.dayItems);
},
```

**I would like to shuffle the items with the underscore.js shuffle function *before* adding indexes.**
Somehow though it seems that those two functions don't like each other as it doesn't return anything when I combine them.

This is what I tried:

```
return _.shuffle(this.dayItems).map(function(item, index) {
    item.index = index;
    return item;
});
```

Thanks

---

**EDIT 2:** Here's some additional code. The items are fetched in the router with this code:

```
dayItems: Items.find({
    gender: "male",
    dayOrNight: "day",
    isOutfit: true,
    isPrecipitation: true,
    tempId: "f",
    published: true,
}, {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit:6}),
```

And interestingly enough, when I shuffle *after* I assign the indexes, it works as expected:

```
return _.shuffle(this.dayItems.map(function(item, index) {
    item.index = index;
    return item;
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so **a.dorosty**'s answer was correct. The problem came from **this.dayItems** which returned a mongo cursor, not an array.

This works:

```
return _.chain(this.dayItems.fetch()).shuffle().map(function(item, index) {
    item.index = index;
    return item;
}).value();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return _.chain(this.dayItems).shuffle().map(function(item, index) {
    item.index = index;
    return item;
}).value();
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I think the problem comes from the shuffle function: I tried to use it separately and it doesn't return the expected array, just a bunch of empty objects